# What is the default value in GetStringExtras of the Intent in ANDROID?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
final int intent = getIntent().getIntExtra("string name",default_value);
```

While online search, says that this value should be 0,
but let's say you are making a simple android game and tracking the score of the user using the Intent method.
Then what should be the default value of the other activities?

Comment: Are you asking for `GetStringExtras` or `GetIntExtra`??+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default_value` value is the return value when your intent don't have any extra with the key of `"string name"`

**For example:-**

Assume you sending data(in your case the score) from one place to another using the intent.
from one place you set the data like `Intent().putExtra("score",5)` and at another place where you want data to receive

you will do using `final int scoreIntent = getIntent().getIntExtra("score",1);`
here your `scoreIntent` will have value **5** as we send.

Now think what if we not send any value and never did  `Intent().putExtra("score",5)` but you still trying to get data in your `scoreIntent`?

In your **scoreIntent** you will have value **1** because it's the default value as we set `getIntent().getIntExtra("score",1);`

when you never have any value in intent with the key "score", you will really just get the default value

**Extra:-** why we need default value? because `int` type cannot be `null`, it should have at least a value, so we generally we use 0